# Android pick file from 'Recent'

Tags: android, android-intent, android-cursor

Below is code which I wrote for pick files from my application

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

This code works fine when I pick files through other file manager apps installed. But while picking a file from `Recent` category it fails while converting selected file `Uri` to absolute path.

```
Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
```

In the above code I get `picturePath` as null whenever I choose file from `Recent` category. Please help me with this.

Comment: Why do you want a path to the file? You can open the image directly from the Uri given to you.

Answer (score 1):

> But while picking a file from Recent category it fails while converting selected file Uri to absolute path

[A `Uri` is not a file](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). There is no reliable means of "converting selected file Uri to absolute path". Please use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to use the content backed by the `Uri`, just like how use an HTTP client API (e.g., `HttpUrlConnection`) to use the content backed by a URL.